# Changes from an inner transaction are not visible from outer

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to update a Company object in a new transaction and expecting the same object to be retrieved having updated parameters. But they are not :( Name does not change. 'after' and 'before' are the same. Database was updated but the outer transaction doesn't know about this. Do you know any workarounds for such a case?

```
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = false)
    public Status newTransactionTest() {
    logger.info("newTransactionTest() INNER");
    Company company = companyDAO.findOne(10000013);
    company.setName(company.getName() + "X");

    return Status.OK;
  }

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
  public Status test() {
    logger.info("test() BEFORE");
    Company company1 = companyDAO.findOne(10000013);
    String before = company1.getName();

    // run in a new transaction
    applicationContext.getBean(beanName, AdminService.class).newTransactionTest();

    logger.info("test() AFTER");
    Company company2 = companyDAO.findOne(10000013);
    String after = company2.getName();

    logger.info("COMPANY NAME BEFORE: " + before);

    logger.info("COMPANY NAME AFTER: " + after);

    return Status.OK;
  }
```

and the logs are:

```
test() BEFORE
connection: 122 select company0_.name as name7_4_0_ ... where company0_.id=5000062
newTransactionTest() INNER
connection: 123 select company0_.name as name7_4_0_ ... where company0_.id=5000062
connection: 123 update Company set name='TestorexX' where id=5000062
connection: 123 commit
test() AFTER
connection: 122 select company0_.name as name7_4_0_ ... where company0_.id=5000062
COMPANY NAME BEFORE: Testorex
COMPANY NAME AFTER: Testorex
```

Comment: Your second `findOne` in the `test()` method isn't going to the database. It simply returns the object from the first level cache, i.e. the same object. You need to `clear` the first level cache if you want it to be refreshed.

Comment: Do you mean to detach ?

Comment: But I see in the JDBC driver logs there is a select query to the db

Comment: Not from the second `findOne` but from the one in the `newTransactionTest` method. Even if there was you will still get the same instance of the bean from the first level cache, that is how JPA works (and as described in the spec).

Comment: so how to remove this object from the first level cache ?

Comment: You have to clear the `EntityManager`... But why are you even doing/trying this?

Comment: Because I have some code that have to be executed in a separate transaction. In case of rollback my outer transaction still can be executed. I deploy this on google cloud and previously this solution was working for me :(

Comment: I have updated the question and added the logs. So you can see the second findOne() is going to the db as well. But actually I hava a clue where the problem may be. As I see Google CloudSQL has transaction isolation level set to REPEATABLE-READ so queries from the outer transaction will give me always the same results. I will change the isolation tomorrow and post here the solution.

Comment: Are you actually using cloudsql or the datastore?

Comment: cloudsql, but on my local mysql I also have REPEATABLE-READ as a defaul

Comment: Ok, thx for your time actually this is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I have fixed this bug. The problem was with a default isolation level which was on my local mySQL instance and Cloud SQL set to REPEATABLE-READ. To check these settings I used:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='tx_isolation'
```

so my repeated queries returned the same result because of cashing done on the db level not as I expected on hibernate/spring

To change REPEATABLE-READ to READ COMMITTED I added this to my persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
```

Where

```
1: READ UNCOMMITTED
2: READ COMMITTED
4: REPEATABLE READ
8: SERIALIZABLE
```

Now everything works fine as it is expected. In the beginning of every new transaction hibernate does

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

The outer transaction sees changes from the inner!